# React - Navigation dropdown with only one dropdown showing at the time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on my first react project and I got a bit stuck.

I am trying to create a navigation menu where when you click, for example, "men", a dropdown appears.

The issue I am having is that there shall only be one of these dropdowns showing at the same time, I have a total of 6 dropdowns.

I have been trying to remove the class from the elements and then re-adding it, but the issue is that it toggles the class back.

Here is the code:

```
const BottomNavigation = (props) => {
  const [menShowing, setMenShowing] = useState(false);
  const [womenShowing, setWomenShowing] = useState(false);
  const [accessoriesShowing, setAccessoriesShowing] = useState(false);
  const [shoesShowing, setShoesShowing] = useState(false);
  const [faceBodyShowing, setFaceBodyShowing] = useState(false);
  const [newInShowing, setNewInShowing] = useState(false);

  const menHandler = () => setMenShowing((prevCheck) => !prevCheck);
  const womenHandler = () => setWomenShowing((prevCheck) => !prevCheck);
  const accessoriesHandler = () =>
    setAccessoriesShowing((prevCheck) => !prevCheck);
  const shoesHandler = () => setShoesShowing((prevCheck) => !prevCheck);
  const faceBodyHandler = () => setFaceBodyShowing((prevCheck) => !prevCheck);
  const newInHandler = () => setNewInShowing((prevCheck) => !prevCheck);

  return (
    <nav>
      <div className={classes.bottom_navigation}>
        <div className={classes.nav_items_container}>
          <ul className={classes.nav_link}>
            <li className={`${classes.nav_item}`}>
              <p onClick={menHandler}>men</p>
              <div
                key="men"
                className={`${classes.nav_dropdown} ${classes.dropdown__men} ${
                  menShowing ? classes.dropdown_show : null
                }`}
              >
                <Men />
              </div>
            </li>
            <li className={classes.nav_item}>
              <p onClick={womenHandler}>women</p>
              <div
                key="women"
                className={`${classes.nav_dropdown} ${
                  classes.dropdown__women
                } ${womenShowing ? classes.dropdown_show : null} `}
              >
                <Women />
              </div>
            </li>
            <li className={classes.nav_item}>
              <p onClick={accessoriesHandler}>accessories</p>
              <div
                key="accessories"
                className={`${classes.nav_dropdown} ${
                  classes.dropdown__accessories
                } ${accessoriesShowing ? classes.dropdown_show : null} `}
              >
                <Accessories />
              </div>
            </li>
            <li className={classes.nav_item}>
              <p onClick={shoesHandler}>shoes</p>
              <div
                key="shoes"
                className={`${classes.nav_dropdown} ${
                  classes.dropdown__shoes
                } ${shoesShowing ? classes.dropdown_show : null} `}
              >
                <Shoes />
              </div>
            </li>
            <li className={classes.nav_item}>
              <p onClick={faceBodyHandler}>face + body</p>
              <div
                key="facebody"
                className={`${classes.nav_dropdown} ${
                  classes.dropdown__facebody
                } ${faceBodyShowing ? classes.dropdown_show : null} `}
              >
                <FaceBody />
              </div>
            </li>
            <li className={classes.nav_item}>
              <p onClick={newInHandler}>new in</p>
              <div
                key="newin"
                className={`${classes.nav_dropdown} ${
                  classes.dropdown__newin
                } ${newInShowing ? classes.dropdown_show : null} `}
              >
                <NewIn />
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.options_container}>
          <div className={classes.icon_container}>
            <span className={classes.cart_sum}>$0.00</span>
            <Cart className={classes.icon} />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.icon_container}>
            <Heart className={classes.icon} />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.icon_container}>
            <Visibility className={classes.icon} />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.icon_container}>
            <User className={classes.icon} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

If any other component is needed to solve this issue, let me know!

Comment: The content of `classes` object can be useful.

Comment: I don't see the usage of React states. I see lots of DOM mutations. Have you tried to use React states?

Comment: @Kunukn I tried to use `useState` a bit in there but didn't really know how to work with it in this scenario. Any recommendation on which one I should use? Did some googling myself but only found tutorials/posts about having a dropdown for a single element., not multiple ones.

Comment: @AhmetEmreKılınç I posted the css code on pastebin, ending: `ENz82MM4`

Comment: Do you mean `dropdown_show` class is readded to the previously selected item when you say "it toggles the class back"? Because I could not reproduce it. In my output, only the last selected item contains the `dropdown_show`class.

Comment: @AhmetEmreKılınç Wanted to add that I updated the code, also edited the post. Pretty much, only one of the `nav_dropdown`s should be able to hold the `dropdown_show` class at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping every item's showing state in different useState's, you can use a single `useState` and a single menu click handler like:

```
const [showItem, setShowItem] = useState(null);

const menuClickHandler = (param) => {
  if (showItem === param) {
    setShowItem(null);
  } else {
    setShowItem(param);
  }
};
```

and in your nav items you can call menu click handler and you can check if the current state is the name of current item like:

```
<li className={`${classes.nav_item}`}>
  <p onClick={() => menuClickHandler("men")}>men</p>
  <div
    key="men"
    className={`${classes.nav_dropdown} ${classes.dropdown__men} ${
    showItem === "men" ? classes.dropdown_show : null
    }`}
  >
      <Men />
  </div>
</li>
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bottom-navigation-vcjx9) for this usage.

Comment: That really made the code a lot cleaner, the only issue I am having is that whenever I click on the navigation again, it doesn't close the dropdown itself. I am guessing I have to set the `showItem` state to `null` again?

Comment: Yes, you have to set `showItem` to `null` again. I have updated the answer and sandbox accordingly. In the new code, if the current state's `showItem` is currently clicked item, then it sets the `showItem` state to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend solving this by making a new component that you can reuse. I'll call mine Dropdown. This takes advantage of React's use of state. We want each dropdown to control it's own state of being open or not. Changing classes *works*, but I don't think you're properly leveraging what React can do.

Here's my quick version of a Dropdown, which you can test out [here](https://replit.com/@DRCardenas/SimpleDropdown?v=1). The tech I use here is mostly [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).

```
import "./dropdown.css";

import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const Dropdown = ({ onOpen, label, children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const containerRef = useRef();

  const onMouseDown = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      if (containerRef.current && !containerRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
        setIsOpen(false);
      }
    },
    [containerRef, setIsOpen]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      onOpen();
    }
  }, [isOpen, onOpen]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
  }, [onMouseDown]);

  const toggleIsOpen = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  }

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} className="dropdown-container">
      <div className="dropdown-label" onClick={toggleIsOpen}>{label}</div>
      {isOpen && <div className="dropdown-content">{children}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

Here it is in action inside of a simple App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="menu">
        <Dropdown
          label={<div>Men</div>}
          onOpen={() => console.log("Opening men")}
        >
          <div>Test Menu</div>
          <div>Test Menu</div>
          <div>Test Menu</div>
        </Dropdown>
        <Dropdown
          label={<div>Women</div>}
          onOpen={() => console.log("Opening women")}
        >
          <div>Test Menu</div>
          <div>Test Menu</div>
          <div>Test Menu</div>
        </Dropdown>
        <Dropdown
          label={<div>Shoes</div>}
          onOpen={() => console.log("Opening shoes")}
        >
          <div>Test Menu</div>
          <div>Test Menu</div>
          <div>Test Menu</div>
          <div>Test Menu</div>
        </Dropdown>
        <Dropdown
          label={<div>Accessories</div>}
          onOpen={() => console.log("Opening accessories")}
        >
          <div>Test Menu</div>
          <div>Test Menu</div>
          <div>Test Menu</div>
          <div>Test Menu</div>
          <div>Test Menu</div>
          <div>Test Menu</div>
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Let me know if you have questions!

Comment: Checked this out on your Replit you linked. Seems to be an issue whenever you try to close the dropdown? Not sure if that only occurs on Replit.

Comment: Ah yes, if you want them to close when clicked, we can change the onClick for the .dropdown-label. I'll do that in the repl so it toggles the state instead of just setting it open.

Comment: There was also a typo in the repl with a missing "!". I've updated these code blocks.

Comment: @DCardenas May I ask why you used `useCallback` here?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the really late reply @dev_el. It's due to the event handler being set in the `useEffect` call. We don't want to pass in the handlers dependencies as dependencies for the effect, so we use `useCallback`. We also need a reference to the handler that doesn't change on re-render, which `useCallback` takes care of.